# ReSharper show warning with SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, sqldatareader

When I write something like this:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
{
    using(var cmd= new SqlCommand("Command"))
    {
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ReSharper shows warning on `reader.Read()`, and tells that reader can be `null`.

But in what cases can it be null? As I know if command returns nothing reader is not null, it only have nothing.

Comment: +1 I noticed that too. Maybe you should ask the people at JetBrains directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that this is reported on YouTrack as a bug (twice - [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-70659) and [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-58796)), it looks like the nullity annotations that are shipped with R# are deficient in this respect.

Have a look in your `ReSharper_installation_dir\Bin\ExternalAnnotations` folder - this is where the annotations files get installed. For me, with v5, there is in here a file `System.Data\System.Data.Nullness.xml` which contains this annotation:

```
<member name="M:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader">
  <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.CanBeNullAttribute.#ctor" />
</member>
```

If by your own inspection you are satisfied that this is wrong, and that `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader` never returns null, you should change this to

```
<member name="M:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader">
  <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />
</member>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it cannot be null - but resharper does not know that `SqlCommand.ExeuteReader()` will never return null.
As far as I know there is some xml they use to tell witch functions may or may not return null and it can be set there. 
I do not know the name and location of the xml though.